# Formatação de números (PHP)

Tags: php

Criei uma função `cotacaoDolar();` que retorna no final:

```
return str_replace(",",".",$texto_dolar);
```

E o resultado, aparece aqui:

```
echo  $i['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice'][0]['__value__'] * cotacaoDolar();
```

Como faço para formatar o valor (`['__value__']`) citado acima?

Está assim: `R$ 271.309389 ou R$ 1119.2445`

O certo seria: `R$ 271,30 ou R$ 1.119,24`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Utilize a função [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php);

```
$valor = 12345678900;

echo number_format($valor,2,",",".");
// 123.245.678.900,00
```

Comment: Beleza, funcionou assim: $valor = $i['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice'][0]['__value__'] * cotacaoDolar();

     echo number_format($valor,2,",",".");

Answer (score 15):

No PHP 5.3 já existe uma [classe](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php) para a formatação de moeda. O primeiro argumento de `NumberFormatter()` é a moeda que é baseada na [ISO 4217](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)

```
$valores = array('530077.99','31459.89', '2899.39', '600.51', '13', '9', '0.25');
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
foreach($valores as $item){
    echo  $formatter->formatCurrency($item, 'BRL') . '<br>';
}
```

O processo inverso, converter um valor moeda para o valor puro para gravar no banco por exemplo, pode ser feito usando o método [parseCurrency](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php)

```
$arr=array('R$530.077,99','R$31.459,89','R$2.899,39','R$600,51','R$13,00','R$9,00','R$0,25');

foreach($arr as $item){
    echo  $formatter->parseCurrency($item, $valor_puro) . '<br>';
}
```

[**Exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0upn-32dh)

Comment: +1 por estimular o uso de novas práticas. Só lembrando que essa classe não é nativa, é parte da biblioteca `intl`.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos, bem lembrado, no windows a _instalação_ deve ser feita removendo o `;` dessa linha `extension=php_intl.dll` no php.ini.

Comment: Interessante este modo, sou um pouco leigo em php, mas vou procurar entender.

Answer (score 9):

Utilize a função number_format.
A função por padrão retorna no formato americano, por isso a necessidade de passar 2 parâmetros, nesse caso o "," e ".".

```
echo 'R$' . number_format($num, 2, ',', '.');
```

Comment: Neste caso, o resultado foi R$ 0,00

Answer (score 6):

Use a funçao [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php):

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// Notação Inglesa (padrão)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,234

// Notação Francesa
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// Notação Inglesa sem separador de milhar
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa função pode ajudar:

```
// Informa as configurações locais que serão usadas na formatação.
// https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');

/**
 * Formata como moeda um valor de acordo com as informações locais.
 * 
 * @param float $val valor que será formatado
 * @return string
 */
function currency(float $val): string
{
    $fmt = new NumberFormatter(setlocale(LC_MONETARY, null), NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    $locale = localeconv();
    return $fmt->formatCurrency($val, $locale['int_curr_symbol']);
}

echo currency(1200.99); // Retorna R$ 1.200,99
```