# Converter para número decimal

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um script que calcula o total de valores e em seguida demostra o valor total em um echo. O problema é que o valor é demostrado sem pontos ou vírgulas, ex: 82700 para: 827.00 gostaria de converte-lo para número decimal mas ainda não está funcionando.

```
<?php // Make a MySQL Connection $con = mysql_connect('', 'flash548_passhms', 'passhms');

if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db("flash548_passhms", $con);

$query = "SELECT month, SUM(overhead) FROM projections_sample GROUP BY month";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Despesas". $row['month']. " R$". $row['SUM(overhead)']; //overhead
    echo "<br />";
} 

?>
```

Comment: O que você quer é o mesmo que esta pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11301/formatacao-de-numeros-php

Comment: @bigown é basicamente isto.

Comment: Duas dicas: 1) `SELECT month, SUM(overhead) AS total FROM` assim você pode usar `$row['total']`. 2) `$row['total']/100` devolve o que você quer (porém, sem formatação). Para formatar, recomendo que veja a resposta indicada pelo @bigown

Answer (score 0):

Parece que os seus dados estão armazenados em centavos, já que retornam do banco como `INT` (baseado na descrição do problema). O mais fácil (assumindo o exposto) é tornar o número decimal na query:

```
SELECT month, ROUND(SUM(overhead)/100, 2) FROM projections_sample GROUP BY month
```

Isto já vai te devolver um decimal para o PHP exibir.

Comment: obrigado pela informação relevante irei testar.

Comment: Olá, Tentei do modo informado mais não aparece nada para visualização, e também nenhum erro é informado: