# Converter número inteiro para decimal em SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho números no banco de dados que estão no formato inteiro. Ex:`12345`
Quero converter ele para o formato de preço, em reais. Ex: `12.345,00`

Comment: Você quer *converter* o tipo da coluna ou somente *formatar* o resultado da query?

Comment: Somente o resultado da query

Comment: Relacionado: [formatação de números php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/91)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para retornar o valor formatado no MySQL, faça assim:

```
SELECT CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(valor, 2));
```

Se você quiser editar o valor no PHP, deve-se usar a função [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format).

```
<?php
$valor = 12345;
$preco = 'R$' . number_format($num, 2, ',', '.'); // R$ 12.345,00
```

Comment: Amigo, quero fazer esta converçao direto na consulta sql

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 Editei a resposta.

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 Então deveria remover a tag [tag:php] da sua pergunta.

Comment: Amigo, exatamente o que queira

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 se a resposta é correta, então marque-a com o sinal "verde" que fica abaixo da seta dos pontos.