# Incompatibilidade entre maskmoney e number_format

Tags: php, javascript, number-format

Tenho um campo de formulário no qual estou utilizando o `maskmoney`, mas quando o número digitado entra no milhar, o `number_format` retorna apenas as quatro primeiras casas decimais.

A chamada do `maskmoney`:

```
$(function(){
        $("#Cultsal").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ',
            showSymbol:true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', symbolStay: true});
```

O campo `input`:

```
            <label for="Cultsal">Digite o valor</label>
        <input id="Cultsal" name="Tultsal" type="text" size="10">
```

O php:

```
         echo "O valor digitado foi de R$ ". number_format($ultsalbase, 2, ",", ".");
```

No entanto, quando a saía é milhar, o php retorna apenas os primeiros quatro dígitos. Por exemplo, se entro com 1000, o maskmoney apresenta 1.000,00, mas o php retorna 10,00. Até a centena funciona normal, tipo, entro com 100, o `maskmoney` mostra 100,00 e o php retorna 100,00. Só dá prolema quando passa pra milhar.

Existe solução, ou terei que utilizar outra máscara?

Edit: Preciso do `number_format` porque quando eu utilizo o valor numa função com outra variável, esta não "herda" a formatação corretamente (não inclui o ",00", às vezes coloca .000 etc). Por exemplo:

```
if ($tiposal=="hora") {
  $rem = ultsalbase * $multipl;
 }
```

Mesmo que eu coloque o `number_format` apenas na outra variável (`$rem` no caso) ele dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pode ajudar [formatação de números](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gustavo, se o campo input já está fazendo a formatação, porquê quer fazer isso novamente no PHP ? Caso queira transformar em money para colocar no banco de dados você deve tirar a vírgula do número e deixar o ponto no lugar da vírgula.
Use o Str_Replace().

Comment: Porque quando eu utilizo o valor em outra variável, ele não inclui o ",00" na saída (vou editar a pergunta sobre isso), então comecei a utilizar o number_format pra formatar a saída. O que eu queria era que o maskmoney apenas mostrasse o número com a formatação para o usuário no preenchimento do campo, e que depois a formatação da saída fosse feita pelo number_format (sem considerar a formatação do masknoney).

Comment: Entendi. Eu costumo usar o Numeral.Js 
http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: Valeu, vou testar aqui.

Comment: Cara, sua dica para incluir no banco de dados funcionou também para o que eu queria! Vou postar uma resposta com a solução. Valeu mais uma vez! Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é a maneira mais efetiva, mas consegui resolver à partir da dica do Diego, da seguinte forma:

```
$ultsalbase = $_POST ["Tultsal"]; // o campo do formulário, que vem com a formatação do maskmoney (1.000,00)
$ultsalbase2 = str_replace('.', '', $ultsalbase); // tira o ponto (fica 1000,00)
$ultsalbase3 = str_replace(',', '.', $ultsalbase2); // muda a vírgula para ponto (fica 1000.00

echo number_format($ultsalbase3, 2, ",", "."); // e a saída é correta, 1.000,00. :-)
```