# Como simplificar o uso do str_replace

Tags: php, declaração-de-variável

Como expliquei [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58593/incompatibilidade-entre-maskmoney-e-number-format), estou utilizando o `maskMoney` para gerar uma máscara de moeda em vários campos `input` do `type="text"`, só que quando realizo operações aritméticas com os valores obtidos, e depois uso o `number_format` na saída, ele dá vários tipos de problema na formatação (não inclui a vírgula, etc).

A solução que encontrei naquele tópico foi a seguinte:

```
$ultsalbase = $_POST["Tultsal"]; 

$ultsalbase2 = str_replace('.', '', $ultsalbase); 
$ultsalbase3 = str_replace(',', '.', $ultsalbase2);
```

Desta forma, quando o valor entra pelo formulário no formato 1.000,00, o `str_replace`o transforma para 1000.00. Aí depois de fazer os cálculos, o `number_format` retorna corretamente os valores em moeda (1.000,00).

O que acontece é que como são muitos campos, estou achando que pode ser errado ter que criar duas novas variáveis para cada campo, apenas pra conseguir mudar a formatação.

Não existe uma solução mais simples pra isso?

Tentei isso:

```
$ultsalbase = $_POST["Tultsal"] . str_replace('.', '', $ultsalbase) . str_replace(',', '.', $ultsalbase);
```

Mas não deu certo. Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma função para aplicar a todos itens necessários de `$_POST`, por exemplo:

```
function formatFromMaskMoney($value) {
    $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
    $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
    $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    return (double) $value;
}

$_POST["variavel-1"] = formatFromMaskMoney($_POST["variavel-1"]);
$_POST["variavel-2"] = formatFromMaskMoney($_POST["variavel-2"]);
$_POST["variavel-3"] = formatFromMaskMoney($_POST["variavel-3"]);
$_POST["variavel-4"] = formatFromMaskMoney($_POST["variavel-4"]);

//exemplo:
echo number_format(formatFromMaskMoney('4.233.456.700, 99') / formatFromMaskMoney('1.000.000,00'), 2, ",", ".");
```

Ou se você quiser para tornar mais fácil você pode aplicar um `array` e usar `array_map`, tal como:

```
function formatFromMaskMoney($key) {
    if (isset($key) && isset($_POST[$key])) {
        $_POST[$key] = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST[$key]);
        $_POST[$key] = str_replace('.', '', $_POST[$key]);
        $_POST[$key] = (double) str_replace(',', '.', $_POST[$key]);
    }

    return $key;
}

$posts = array('variavel-1', 'variavel-2', 'variavel-3', 'variavel-4');
array_map('formatFromMaskMoney', $posts);

echo number_format($_POST['variavel-1'] / $_POST['variavel-2'], 2, ",", ".");
```

E você também pode fazer a função verificar se o campo é um valor de dinheiro e aplicar o `str_replace`:

```
function formatFromMaskMoney($value) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9.]+[,]( |)\d{2}$/', $value) !== 0) {
        $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
        $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
        $value = (double) str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    }

    return $value;
}

$_POST = array_map('formatFromMaskMoney', $_POST);
print_r($_POST);//Para verificar os dados antes de usa-los.

echo number_format($_POST['variavel-1'] / $_POST['variavel-2'], 2, ",", ".");
```

Exemplo online no ideone: https://ideone.com/HScQXG

Comment: Vixi, essa foi à jato! Valeu! (utilizei a primeira opção)

Comment: Então, do outro jeito funcionou perfeitamente, mas desse parece bem mais elegante! :) Estou tentando aqui, e ele inclui automático todos os `number_format` (muito legal!), mas as variáveis que solucionam as operações artiméticas aparecem sem formatação, e com erro no cálculo. Ah, e por sugestão da IDE eu mudei onde está `key` por `value`, daí funcionou, mas da forma como disse acima...

Comment: Sim, o último. Valeu!

Comment: Então, o erro de cálculo persiste, mas se eu tiro a função `$value = number_format($value, 2, ',', '.');` da função, daí ele converte do `maskmoney` e faz os cálculos certinho. Será que é melhor criar duas funções, uma pro `maskmoney` e outra pro `number_format`? Porque parece que ele tá fazendo tudo "de uma vez só", antes de fazer o cálculo... Cara valeu demais pela ajuda, a cada dia fico mais impressionado com a qualidade das respostas aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Então, ainda persiste... Preciso sair agora, mais tarde vou fazer uns testes aqui pra ver se o problema não é no meu código, e posto os resultados... Valeu por enquanto! Abraços!

Comment: @gustavox vacilo meu confundi o `array_map`, com outra função de array para PHP, o uso correto é `$_POST = array_map('formatFromMaskMoney', $_POST);`, editei a resposta.

Comment: Então, o que acontece é que as variáveis que não vêm do formulário, que apenas realizam operações, por exemplo: Com `$ultsalbase = formatFromMaskMoney ($_POST ["Tultsal"]);` pego o valor do formulário. E com `$remmes = formatFromMaskMoney($ultsalbase)` passo ele pra outra variável. Daí eu tenho uma variável `$multipl` cujo valor é 220. Daí se faço `$remhora = formatFromMaskMoney($remmes / $multipl);` os cálculos saem errados. Mas quando tiro o `number_format` da função', e coloco direto na saída, aí fica perfeito...

Comment: A entendi então você só precisa do `number_format` no final, veja a minha edição, calma ae.

Comment: No caso acima, por exemplo, a saída com o campo no formulário "Tultsal" preenchido em 2.800,00 e o multiplicador em 220, a saída deveria ser R$ 12,73 (o que sai se tiro o `number_format` da função'). Mas com ele na função R$ 1,38. O `var_dump` retorna:  float(1.375)

Comment: @gustavox acho que o number_format só pode ser usado depois do calculo, então atualizei a resposta e adicionei alguns exemplos de como proceder.

Comment: É isso mesmo! Agora ficou perfeito, e nem precisa do primeiro`$value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);` e do `(double)` no último value. Tá perfeito, valeu mesmo!

Comment: @gustavox o `str_replace` é só para facilitar e o `double` é para converter a string em numerico. Mas no PHP as variaveis são dinamicas então realmente o double não é necessário, mas recomendo remover os espaços. Boa noite

Comment: Ok, já inclui de novo aqui. Boa noite pra vc também e obrigado novamente! Abraço!