# Problema com valor que contém vírgula

Tags: php, mysql

Ao executar essa consulta:

```
mysqli_query($dbc, "insert into toons values(NULL, $toonId, '$toonName', $admin, '$dna', $bank, $money, $hp, '$inventory', $lastPlace)")
```

Eu recebo esse erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' '', , '', , , , '', )' at line 1

O que está causando isso?

Comment: Verifique se o money está formatado com virgula (,).

Comment: Sim está, como pode verificar no código.

Comment: Relacionada, [Formatação de números php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/91)

Answer (score 3):

Banco de dados só aceita casas decimais com `.` (ponto). Se você estiver passando `1,99` na variável money é provável que dê problema não só no banco. Usa um replace na variável de `,` para `.`.

```
mysqli_query($dbc, "insert into toons values(NULL, $toonId, '$toonName', $admin, '$dna', $bank, str_replace(",", ".", $money), $hp, '$inventory', $lastPlace)")
```