# Como retirar formatação de moeda e pegar só o número em PHP?

Tags: php, string, formatação, valor-monetário

Eu gravo no banco de dados os valores dos produtos dessa forma:

Por exemplo:

```
R$ 5.000,00
```

Como eu faço no PHP pra fazer esse número ficar 5000? Ou seja "desformatar"?

Tem alguma função que sirva pra qualquer número? Algo assim?

Comment: [formatação de números](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/91)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Acho que é o [`NumberFormatter::parseCurrency()`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) que você quer.

```
$formatter = numfmt_create('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
var_dump(numfmt_parse_currency($formatter, "R$ 5.000,00", "BRL"));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/FormatMoney.php).

Não sei se este módulo está disponível por padrão nas instalações. Tentei rodar no ideone e não foi.

Dá para fazer manualmente também, mas dá trabalho e é fácil errar alguma coisa, não tratar alguma situação, resolver números mal formatados, etc.

Comment: Para ter acesso a essas funções/objetos é preciso habilitar a [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) antes.

Answer (score 4):

você pode fazer de um jeito mais simples também, veja se funciona:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'pt_BR');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
```

Comment: Só uma observação [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) não funciona no windows.

Comment: @rray eu perdi alguma coisa ou não funciona para esta pergunta? Até onde eu sei isto converte o número para o formato da moeda, e a pergunta é converter um número que está em formato de moeda e voltar para um número simples.

Comment: @bigown ele editou a pergunta.

Comment: Não, ele não editou. Tem *log* de edição. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/79898/revisions

Comment: o `money_format` toma um número e foramta, em vez de tomar um número formatado e tirar o formato

Answer (score 2):

A conversão pode ser feita de forma simples assim:

```
$str = '99.999,99';
$str = str_replace('.', '', $str); // remove o ponto
echo str_replace(',', '.', $str); // troca a vírgula por ponto
// resulta em 99999.99
```

Pode também usar a classe [numberformatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php), específicamente o método [parsecurrency](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php), caso esteja habilitado no ambiente onde pretende executar o código. Particularmente prefiro sanitizar com o `str_replace`, conforme mostrado acima pois normalmente essa classe não vem instalada por padrão. Num hosting compartilhado, por exemplo, dificilmente conseguirá ter esse recurso e no final das contas terá que implementar com `str_replace` ou regex.