# Validando dinheiro de saída do Jquery Price Format

Tags: php

Estou usando o Jquery Price Format para formatar o dinheiro usando a `,(vírgula)`

para separar centavos e o `.(ponto)` para separar milhares, ficando algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso validar isso aceitando somente números,pontos e vírgulas?

obs: o prefixo **R$** não é enviado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Retirar formatação de moeda e pegar só o número em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/79898/retirar-formata%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-moeda-e-pegar-s%c3%b3-o-n%c3%bamero-em-php)

Comment: Você já viu o plugin `maskedinput` do jQuery? http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#usage

Comment: Sim, mas como já usava o Jquery Price... mas mesmo assim essa validação é só client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No PHP você pode usar um regex para validar o dado:

```
$valid = preg_match('/^(\d{1,3}\.)*?(\d{1,3}),\d{2}$/','99.999,99');
```

A variável `$valid` vai armazenar o valor booleano que vai te informar se o valor está correto (true), ou se não está correto (false).

[Expressões regulares](http://www.devmedia.com.br/expressoes-regulares-em-php/25076)

Comment: Obrigado, fiz alguns testes e funcionou legal:)

Answer (score 2):

uma das soluções é utilizar um pattern no campo input

segue um ex:

```
<input type="number" pattern="^[R$\-\s]*[\d\.]*?([\,]\d{0,2})?\s*$" />
```

isso valida as seguintes entradas

```
1 => true
1,00 => true
R$1 => true
R$1000 => true
0,1 => true
1.000,00 => true
R$1.000.000 => true
5678 => true
```

e invalida estas outras

```
1,001 => false
02,0 => false
22.42 => false
001 => false
192,168,1,2 => false
. => false
,55 => false
2000.000 => false
```

alem disso vc trabalha com a mascara do campo para obrigar a utilização desses dados.

Comment: Mas dessa forma seria só client side né? isso dá pra burlar fácil.

Comment: mas dai vc validaria o resto no seu php ou linguagem q vc usa de backend tbm comexpressao regular do jeito q eu fiz vc so adapta pro preg_replace do php

Comment: Essa foi a pergunta rs