# Ler uma arquivo txt pelo php e mysql e visualizado por cada usuário - PARTE 2

Tags: php, mysql

Estava indo tudo bem até que eu me deparei com uma situação que não consegui resolver até o momento. Não consegui ajustar os valores totais do arquivo.

O exemplo abaixo mostra como ele o valor está. E deverá ficar assim (R$ 335,43). Já tentei inserir alguns códigos para alterar a posição da vírgula e do ponto, mas não tive êxito.

Alguns códigos que coloque foram como este:

```
echo "Valor: R$ ".number_format($data[5], 0,',','.')
```

mas não deu resultado. Abaixo está todo o script.

ID: 000001
MÃªs: 06
Ano: 2015
Ordem: 001
Entidade: UNIMED EMPRESARIAL (PL ANTIGO) 
Valor: R$ 33.543

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',0);
error_reporting(0);
?>
<?php 
$conecta = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("meu_banco_dados",$conecta);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO extratos (usuario,senha,mes,ano,ordem,ref,total,cod) values";
 $dados = mysql_query("select * from minha_tabela"); 

$arquivo = fopen("meu_arquivo.txt", "r");
if ($arquivo) {
    $total = 0;
    while (($line = fgets($arquivo)) !== false) {

        $data = explode("|",$line);

        echo "ID: ".$data[0]."</br>";
        echo "Mês: ".$data[1]."</br>";
        echo "Ano: ".$data[2]."</br>";
        echo "Ordem: ".$data[3]."</br>";
        echo "Entidade: ".$data[4]."</br>";
        echo "Valor: R$ ".number_format($data[5], 0,',','.')."</br>";
        echo "Cod: ".$data[6]."</br>";
    }

    echo '</br>Total: R$' . number_format($total, 0,',','.');

    fclose($arquivo);
} else {
} 

?>
```

Comment: O problema é só formatar o valor como dinheiro?

Comment: qual é o valor do arquivo e como quer que fique? 33.543 é igual a 33,543

Comment: [Formatação de números](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/91)

Comment: O valor tem que ficar em R$ 335,43.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer da seguinte maneira:
Trocar:

```
echo "Valor: R$ ".number_format($data[5], 0,',','.')."</br>";
```

Por:

```
echo "Valor: R$ ".number_format(str_replace(",", ".", $data[5]),2,',','.')."</br>";
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Até substituir o ,2, pelo "0", mas ainda a posição da vírgula não mudou.  _ID: 000001
MÃªs: 06
Ano: 2015
Ordem: 001
Entidade: UNIMED EMPRESARIAL (PL ANTIGO) 
Valor: R$ 33.543_ O certo é ficar R$ 335,43

Comment: como ela esta no arquivo? assim '33543'?

Comment: Sim. Com vários zeros e depois o valor. "00000033543".