# Regra no model para formatar data

Tags: cakephp

Estou com duas regras em dois campos.

No campo data_despesa, quero pegar do formato `d/m/a` e passar para `a-m-d`. Acontece que quando salva no banco, fica como `0000-00-00`. Não sei debugar no model para ver como está transformando e no controller, quando debugo o `$this->request->data`) não pega com a validação.

O campo `valor_despesa` está ok. Está trocando a "," por ".". O problema é somente na formatação de `data_despesa`.

O que há de errado?

Segue o código do model:

```
<?php

class Despesa extends AppModel {

    public $name='despesa';
    public $useTable='despesas';
    public $primaryKey='id_despesa';

    public $validate=array(
'data_despesa'=>array(  
    'data'=>array(
'rule'=>array('data'))),

'valor_despesa'=>array( 
'preco'=>array(
'rule'=>array('preco'))));

    public function data($check) {
        $dataDespesa=explode("/", $check['data_despesa']);

        $dataDaDespesa="";

        $dataDaDespesa=$dataDespesa[2]."-".$dataDespesa[1]."-".$dataDespesa[0];

        return true;
    }  

    public function preco($check) {
        $valorDespesa=str_replace(",", ".", $check['valor_despesa']);

        return true;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Se usar `<pre><code>` para formatar a pergunta, o prettify do site não funciona: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: o campo `data_despesa` está com o tipo `date` no Banco de Dados? Se sim, o formato `yyyy-MM-dd` é o formato padrão dos campos tipo 'date'. O que você pode fazer é modelar este valor para mostrar na tela, mas os campos de data sempre salvarão neste formato no Banco de Dados. Se fosse possível salvar de qualquer maneira, o Banco de Dados teria problemas para comparar duas datas.

Comment: @DennnE
 o que eu quero é mudar de d/m/a para y-m-d eu consegui no controller, mas no model, não consigo. Estava uma gambiarra essa validação no controller, por isso quero implementar no model.

Answer (score 2):

Para mudar o formatado da data de um objeto `DateTime` que provavelmente o cake usa, use o método `format()`.

Mude:

```
public function data($check) {
    $dataDespesa=explode("/", $check['data_despesa']);
    $dataDaDespesa="";
    $dataDaDespesa=$dataDespesa[2]."-".$dataDespesa[1]."-".$dataDespesa[0];
    return true;
}
```

para:

```
public function data($check) {
    $dataDespesa = $check['data_despesa']->format('Y-m-d');
    return true;
}
```

Não conheço o cake, talvez seja necessário mudar o `return true` para  `return $dataDespesa`.

Como formatar valores monetários no PHP veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11308/91)