# como formatar um valor em pt-br

Tags: php

Galera atualmente uso o seguinte código em php para formatar um valor em PT-BR (22.222,22)

```
// Colocar valor no padram 0,000,000.00 
$valor_antigo = "22222.22";
$valor = number_format($valor_antigo, 2, ',', '.');
```

Minha dúvida e como fazer isso de forma ao contrária.

Comment: [Formatação de números](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11308/91)

Comment: vlw, com isso cheguei a uma solução

Answer (score 2):

A solução e esta:

```
$valores = '530222077.99';


$formatter = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$valores = $formatter->formatCurrency($valores, 'BRL');


echo $valores;

echo "<br><hr><br>";


$valor_puro = $formatter->parseCurrency($valores, $valor_puro);


echo $valor_puro;
```