# Corrigir Soma resultado php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Codigo usado para obter o resultado

```
<?php
   $total = 0;
   while($row = mysql_fetch_object($trabalho)) {                                    
      $total += $row->valor;
      echo "<tr><td>$row->os</td><td>$row->descricao</td><td>$row->valor</td></tr>";
   }
   echo "<tr><td colspan="3">TOTAL: $total</td></tr>";
?>
```

Como faço para exibir o valor correto

resultado da soma no php e no mysql

`R$: 237688.6`

Resultado desejado

`R$: 237688.60`

Pessoal eu usei o codigo publicado pelo Eduardo Silva que resolve meu problema em varias parte no meu sistema mas encontrei um codigo que talves possa ajudar muita gente aqui

[Formatação de números (php)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11301/formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-n%C3%BAmeros-php)

formartar codigo

`<?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($recibo_pagador)) {
      echo "<tr><td>$row->nome_empresa</td><td>$row->nome_cliente</td><td>$row->data_recibo</td><td>R$ ";
      echo number_format($row->valor_recibo,2,",",".");
      echo "</td><td><a href='print_recibo_recebedor.php?id=$row->id_recibo' class='btn grey darken-3'>Imprimir</a></td></tr>";
        }
 ?>`

Comment: Por favor nos mostre o que você fez para conseguir seus resultados

Comment: Não como comentário Cristiano, edite sua pergunta e coloque o código lá, é mais fácil de visualizar

Comment: [Formatação de números php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/91)

Comment: Não seria melhor você mudar o tamanho da casa decimal na sua coluna do banco? Seria menos código para o PHP processar

Comment: esta assim  decimal(10,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo '<tr><td colspan="3">TOTAL: ' . number_format($total, 2, ".", "") . '</td></tr>';
```

Onde:

- **1º parâmetro:** número a ser formatado.
- **2º parâmetro:** quantidade de casas decimais.
- **3º parâmetro:** dígito separador de decimais.
- **4º parâmetro:** dígito separador de milhares.

Comment: Obrigado Eduardo

Comment: Eduardo tem como voce me ajudar a formatar meu codigo dessa parte ai? nao estou conseguindo exibir dessa forma que voce colocou apenas usando varios `echo`

Comment: O seu código completo é aquele que você adicionou à pergunta, @CristianoCardosoSilva?

Comment: Esse mesmo Eduardo