# Como formatar valor monetários no Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, formatação, valor-monetário

Gostaria de saber como formatar valores monetários no Laravel. Existe algum Pacote ou método que seja para o *framework*?

`{{ $lst->vl_valor_tot_c‌​ontrato }}` seja exibida com formatação monetária como este: `(R$ 105.273,54)`

Comment: Poderia postar o trecho do código em que precisa de ajuda? Ajudaria a comunidade a entender o seu problema.

Comment: Simples @FelipePaetzold ... {{ $lst->vl_valor_tot_contrato }} seja exibida com formatação monetária Ex. R$ 105.273,54

Comment: No seu caso acredito que seria melhor você criar uma máscara js ou usar a biblioteca Money do jquery (https://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para fazer isso do lado do servidor com PHP use a função [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Por exemplo:

```
{{ money_format('%n', $lst->vl_valor_tot_c‌​ontrato ) }}
```

Não se esqueça também de setar o locale corretamente no PHP.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'pt_BR');
```

---

Se a função `money_format` não estiver disponível na sua instalação, também é possível obter o resultado com a função [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
{{  'R$ '.number_format($lst->vl_valor_tot_c‌​ontrato, 2, ',', '.') }}
```

---

**Fontes**:

1. [SOEn - Using number_format method in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27651808/664577)
2. [SOpt - Formatação de números (php)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/100)