# Pegar valor após o ponto

Tags: php

Bom tenho a seguinte variável.

```
$valor = "235.33333333333333";
```

Preciso retornar o valor com apenas 2 casas decimais (235.33). Como posso fazer isso? Usando o explode?

Comment: Seria [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/91)?

Comment: não quero fazer nenhum tipo de formatação, apenas quero cortar os campos após o ponto, e manter apenas 3 dígitos após o pronto.

Comment: Não faz muito sentido você fazer isso com explode, use a função number_format.

Comment: Assim resolve?
$padded = sprintf('%0.2f', $valor);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando `explode` você pode fazer assim:

```
$valor = "235.33333333333333";

$s = explode('.' $valor);

$result = $s[0] . '.' . substr($s[1], 0, 2);

print_r($result); // 235.33
```

Mas eu recomendo você fazer com o [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Com `number_format`:

```
$valor = "235.33333333333333";

$result = number_format($valor, 2);

print_f($result); // 235.33
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra opção seria utilizar o round.

```
$valor = "235.33333333333333";
echo round($valor, 2); #235.33
```

Comment: só tem que tomar cuidado pq o round serve para arredondar para cima, e em algumas lógicas isso pode ser um problema. Se o número fosse 235.6666666 por exemplo ele mostraria 235.67