# Formatar string/float para moeda em PHP

Tags: php, funções

Estou fazendo relatórios em PHP e tenho uma coluna de valor, só que essa coluna pode vir valores com ponto OU virgulas. Preciso que na hora de exibir o valor, mostre ele no formato de dinheiro.
Exemplo de alguns valores de como está no Banco de dados:

```
0,0123
1.7481
0.4875
,14571
```

Exemplo de como eu preciso que mostre no relatório:

```
R$ 0,01
R$ 1,74
R$ 0,49
R$ 0,15
```

Eu não consigo desenvolver nenhuma função que me atenda nesses casos, alguém sabe como posso desenvolver essa função?

Comment: Relacionda: [Formatação de números php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/91)

Comment: Conforme o que foi relacionado pelo autor da pergunta este link não resolve a situação dele devido as valores que o mesmo possui no banco de dados.

Comment: Tente isto `return number_format(str_replace(',', '.', ',14571'), 2, ',', '.');`, até ira funcionar nestes casos ali que passou, porém se houver alguma outra variação em seu banco de dados, acredito que não ira funcionar da mesma forma.

Comment: @DavidSantos Tentei utilizar esse exemplo que me passou, só que quando há valores como por exemplo, 1.090,00 (mil e noventa), ele retorna R$1,09 (um real e nove centavos)

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Exatamente @Huhifeku, como eu citei se você tivesse mais variações de dados no seu banco ela não iria funcionar. O que você pode fazer agora que você já tem uma base é uma função que prevê todas estas variações, neste caso ali que me passou você pode usar assim `number_format(str_replace(['.', ','], ['', '.'], '1.090,00'), 2, ',', '.');` desta forma ele vai substituir o "ponto" por "nada" e a "vírgula" por "ponto".

Comment: Já tentei fazer desse jeito @DavidSantos e me funcionou para esse casso especifico com 1.090,00, mas os outros valores como por exemplo o 1.7481, ficou 17.481,00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que esse codigo seja a solução

```
 $num = array("11.111.090,00" , "111.090,00", "090,00" , "0.4875");

 foreach ($num as $value) {
     if (strpos($value, "0") == 0){
         $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
         $value = number_format($value, 2, ',', '.');
         echo "R$ " . $value . " reais<br>";
     }else{
         $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
         $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
         $value = number_format($value, 2, ',', '.');
         echo "R$ " . $value . " reais<br>";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Informa as configurações locais que serão usadas na formatação.
// https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');

/**
 * Formata como moeda um valor de acordo com as informações locais.
 * 
 * @param float $val valor que será formatado
 * @return string
 */
function currency(float $val): string
{
    $fmt = new NumberFormatter(setlocale(LC_MONETARY, null), NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    $locale = localeconv();
    return $fmt->formatCurrency($val, $locale['int_curr_symbol']);
}

echo currency(1200.99); // Retorna R$ 1.200,99
```