# Converter valor decimal em um valor de moeda

Tags: php

Estou precisando converter o número `4.500.00` para `4500,00`.

Estou fazendo assim mas não está dando certo:

```
$valor3=number_format($valor, 3, ',', '.');
```

O que eu poderia fazer?

Comment: A função `number_format` espera como primeiro parâmetro um *float*. Se seu valor é `4.500.00`, ele com certeza não é um *float*. Comece verificando isso.

Comment: teria alguma referência?

Comment: Tem a [documentação oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Formatar string/float para moeda em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241057/formatar-string-float-para-moeda-em-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse exemplo, os centavos devem existir sempre, senão a saída será errada.

```
$num = "1.154.500.00";
$valor = substr_replace($num, ',', -2, -2);
$valor = str_replace('.', '', $valor);
echo "R$ " . $valor . "<br>";
```

Saída: `R$ 1154500,00`

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, na sua pergunta acho que você quis dizer:

> Preciso converter esse numero 4.500.00 por esse **4500,00**. Estou fazendo assim mas não está dando certo.

Se for isso mesmo, fiz um teste assim e deu certo:

```
<?php
    $valor  = 4500;
    $valor3 = number_format($valor, 2, ',', '');
    echo $valor3;    
?>
```

Comment: coloque o valor=4.500.00 não está dando certo

Comment: Wagner, não estou entendendo sua dúvida. Para usar a função number_format você precisa de um Float, da forma que você está falando, seria um String "4.500,00". Se puder descrever melhor sua necessidade seria mais fácil de ajuda-lo...