# Converter resultado de operação para milhar em PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde. Não consigo converter o resultado da minha função para milhar, já tentei converter com algumas funções nativas do *PHP* sem sucesso.

```
function CafeGenerator() {
    $data_inicial = "2019-02-10";
    $data_atual = date('Y-m-d');
    $valor_inicial = 19900;
    $valor_a_somar = 30; // add 30 xicaras de café a cada dia

    // faz a diferença entre as datas desejadas e converte para dias
    $diferencaentredatasemmilissegundos =strtotime($data_atual) - strtotime($data_inicial);
    $diferencaemdias = intval($diferencaentredatasemmilissegundos/86400);

    // efetua a soma desejada
    $valorfinal = $valor_inicial + ($diferencaemdias * $valor_a_somar);
    return $valorfinal;

}

IMPRIME: 28120

Preciso do resultado: 28.120
```

Comment: Dentre essas funções nativas, você tentou a `number_format`?

Comment: Number Format não tentei floatval etc..

Comment: Consegui assim $valor_formatado = number_format($valorfinal,0,',','.');  Nossa estava tentando o mais difícil obrigado.

Comment: Removo a pergunta admin?

Comment: Se conseguir, pode fechar como duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/5878